# Django 1.5 does not Get static files in development

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am new to Django and really confused about this.

Here are relevant parts in settings.py:

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = 'http://http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT+'/static/')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT + '/templates/')
```

My project file structure is like this:

```
MyProj
    manage.py
    MyProj
      settings.py
      urls.py  
      templates
         base.html
      static
         css
         js
```

In base.html starts with:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
```

but django does not get none of the static files:

```
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3402
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2089
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2122
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2074
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/js/prettify.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2068
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2083
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2089
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3402
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:06] "GET /static/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2122
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:19] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2089
[15/Oct/2013 05:36:20] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2089
```

I'v read the  Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) and tried several alternative settings but none did help to resolve the problem. So appreciate your hints.

url.spy

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^$', 'myproj.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^myproj/', include('myproj.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Could you post your urls.py? Is DEBUG set to True?

Comment: urls.py added. Yes, DEBUG is set to True.

Answer (score 2):

Staticfiles in Django seems to always confuse people who are just starting out, and imo, the documentation could be improved.

Here's a quick breakdown of what's what:

**MEDIA_ROOT**: The base directory where files you upload as part of a form or model form go. The `upload_to` property of a File/ImageField is appended to this path.

**MEDIA_URL**: The URL pattern that files located in MEDIA_ROOT are accessible via.

**STATIC_ROOT**: The directory that holds static files to be served in *production*.

**STATIC_URL**: The URL pattern that files located in STATIC_ROOT are accessible via.

**STATICFILES_DIRS**: The director(y/ies) that hold static files to be served in *development*.

When you have the staticfiles app in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, it will only serve static files located in `STATICFILES_DIRS` when `DEBUG = True`.

When you run `$ python manage.py collectstatic`, it will gather any static directories for your application, and any 3rd party applications and copy them to `STATIC_ROOT`.

So, to fix your paths to static files in production, make sure your settings are correct and that you've run `collectstatic` either before you deploy or as part of your deployment process.

There is also a new template tag for static files:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      ...
      <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"
          rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css' %}"
          rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      ...
```

In your project structure, re-name "/static" to "/static-assets" and set that directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Change your `STATIC_ROOT` to point to "/static", and don't put any directories or files there yourself. Let the `collectstatic` management command do that.

Here's how I typically structure a project:

```
/my_app/
    /my_app/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py

    manage.py

    /another_app_module/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        ...
    /static/
    /static-assets/
        /css
        /js
        /images
    /templates
```

Given this file structure, and assuming my project sits at: `/home/btaylor/django-projects/my_app/` my settings would be:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/btaylor/django-projects/my_app/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/btaylor/django-projects/my_app/static/uploads'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/uploads/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/btaylor/django_projects/my_app/static-assets',)
```

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. but I'm still struggling to apply it to paths. Appreciate some real examples based on the file structure above.

Comment: I added a project directory structure and example HTML for you.

Comment: sorry, I get 'ImproperlyConfigured: Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?
' when I run collectstatic. what should be the STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: Tuples *always* have a trailing comma, even if there is only one element in the tuple. You need to add a comma after the element in your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.

Comment: I get OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied from : '/static',  when I run collectstatic at STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/supermario/myproj/static',) and static is world writable. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this on your development machine? or your production server?

Comment: It's my Ubuntu development machine and I user virtualenv.

Comment: Did you change your STATIC_ROOT to point to /static and your STATICFILES_DIRS to point to /static-assets ?

Comment: I just set STATICFILES_DIRS = '/home/supermari/myproj/static-assets',) and STATIC_ROOT= '/home/supermario/myproj/static'. the  collectstatic have copied only 'admin' folder to /home/supermario/myproj/static and now none of the css and js being requested from webserver.

Comment: Could you please add your working STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS paths for your example file structure?

Comment: I added settings based on my sample project structure.